# Show that $\nabla \times (\mathbf{c}\times \mathbf{r}) = 2\mathbf{c}$

Tags: summation, vectors

Suppose $r=x_i\mathbf{e}_i$

I need to do this question using the Einstein summation convention. So far I have:

$\nabla \times (\mathbf{c}\times \mathbf{r}) = \varepsilon_{ijk} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_j } \varepsilon_{kmn}c_mx_n$

$=\varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{kmn}c_m \frac{\partial x_n}{\partial x_j}$

$= \varepsilon_{ijk}\varepsilon_{kmn} c_m \delta_{nj}$

$=\varepsilon_{jki}\varepsilon_{jkm}c_m$

$=(\delta_{kk} \delta_{im} - \delta_{km}\delta_{ik})c_m$

$=\delta_{kk}\delta_{im}c_m - \delta_{km}\delta_{ik}c_m$

$=\delta_{kk}c_i - \delta_{ik}c_m$

Now I'm stuck. Thanks for help in advance!

Comment: In your last equation, you did not contract indices properly. That $c_m$ should be $c_k$. Also, what is the trace of the knocker delta?

Comment: Yes, I've now spotted that mistake thanks to Michael. I've never heard of the "trace" before.

Comment: Ok good! It might also be worthwhile to note that in the first line, the curl or cross product does not equal the equation with the indices, but it's components are equal to that.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should have put $[...]_{i}$, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All correct up to your last line.  The second term should be $\delta_{im}c_m=c_i$
and remember that $\delta_{kk}=3$ in three-dimensional space.

Comment: Of course, thank you! It's the first I've heard that $\delta_{kk} =3$, we were never given that as a theorem. However, that has just answered a lot of other questions I had! Thank you!